# How to set separator between list element properly with CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple list like this, and I want to use | as the separator between each list item. How can I do this properly?

```css
ul{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Current output:
Item 1 Item 2 Item 3

Expected output:
Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3

The easiest way I can think of is to include the separator as an HTML element, it does look good to me for wrapping it with `<li>`, as their content semantically is irrelevant with the list.  Besides, using a tag other than `<li>` in `<ul>/<ol>` is forbidden.

What is the best way to approach this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `border` which is the easiest way to achieve.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But still this does not center the separator.  Maybe there is a better way to do this?

Comment: What does it mean by `center the separator`?

Comment: I mean I want the separator locates in the middle of two items.

Comment: It should be at the middle of items now. Anyway you can adjust `padding-right` and `margin-right` to get the correct position.

Answer (score 0):

You can user `after` element in your li to assign | every after li.

```
ul{
  diplay: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center
}

ul li {
  position:relative;
  margin:0 2px;
  padding:0 2px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
ul li:after {
  position:absolute;
  content:'|';
  right:-5px;
}
ul li:first-child {
  margin-left:0;
}
ul li:last-child {
  margin-right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear whether you want to retain the bullet point markers or the `<ul>`'s default left padding. Assuming you don't, you can simply use `display:contents` with a `::before` pseudo-element on each `<li>` element except the first to make the separators their own flex-items. Like this:

```css
ul{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: contents;
}
li + li::before {
  content: '|';
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

If you do want the bullet point markers, you'll need to add another element inside the `<li>` elements to restore them. Like this:

```css
ul{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: contents;
}
li + li::before {
  content: '|';
}
li > span {
  display:list-item;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Item 1</span></li>
  <li><span>Item 2</span></li>
  <li><span>Item 3</span></li>
</ul>
```